# As a Philosophy stack I think we should be unique

Tags: discussion, status-declined, meta

I believe with metaphysics being a large part of philosophy, we should have a meta-meta stack.

I am not quite sure if we can find a concrete purpose for it.

One possible idea I had was that it could serve the same function, but for our meta, rather than the parent stack.

Thoughts?

Comment: I'm having a hard time telling if you are serious or just trolling.

Comment: @stoicfury I am 100% serious. Have you no imagination?

Comment: @stoicfury also kinda rude...

Comment: I am reminded of [xkcd sucks](http://xkcdsucks.blogspot.com/) and [xkcd sucks sucks](http://xkcdsuckssux.blogspot.com/), and so on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few problems with this suggestion:

1. Just because philosophy includes metaphysics does not mean we need anything different than StackOverflow which has metaprogramming as a sub top topic or Cross Validated which has meta-analyses as one of is sub topics.
2. Meta.PSE is perfectly suitable for all levels of meta questions. The important separation is between the main content site and the meta site.
3. Meta.PSE barely has any traffic, a meta-meta-PSE would have none.
4. Off you you yourself are unsure of the concrete purpose, why would you suggest it?

So then, please take this criticism in the spirit it is meant, as constructive: not only was stoicfury not rude, but this suggestion is terrible, and future contributions to the community should be better thought out.

Comment: Thanks. I am relatively new to Stack Exchange in general